# Add/get data to/from two Dimensional array Doesn't work

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to add data from database to 2-dimensional array and then unpacking.

This function is in a folder named `imsConnection.php`

```
function getCurrency() {
  global $cn;
  $sql = "select * from Currency";
  $res = mysqli_query($cn, $sql);
  $a = array();
  if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {
      $a[] = array($row['currencyID'], $row['currencyName']);
    }
  }
  return $a;
}
```

And to unpack it into drop box:

```
<select name="drpCurrency" required>
  <?php
    require_once("imsConnection.php");
    $a = getCurrency();
    foreach($a as $i) {
      echo "<option value='$i'>$a[$i]</option>";
    }
  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: You don't need `$a[$i]` as `$i` is already the element - just echo the `$i['currencyName']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a formal answer: If you create multi dimentaion array and you loop with `foreach` you need to echo the value according the key you need. In you case:

```
    foreach($a as $i)
        echo "<option value='" . $i["currencyID"] ."'>" . $i['currencyName'] . "</option>";
```

I recommend you change your array do be according key - change the `getCurrency` function as:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    $a[$row['currencyID']] = $row['currencyName'];
```

Then you can use it as:

```
$a = getCurrency();
foreach($a as $k => $i)
    echo "<option value='$k'>$i/option>";
```

**Assuming** you want the value as currency ID and the option content as the currency name